# Cluster validation error in GCP DataProc : Requested number of primary workers must be within autoscaler min/max range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataproc

We are trying to spin up a DataProc cluster in GCP. We get the below errors when we do so:

The first error is related to primary worker group and the second is to secondary worker group of nodes.
In our configuration file, we have NOT requested 2 (primary) or 0 (secondary) nodes anywhere for the primary/secondary; but somehow validator picks these values.

```
Requested number of primary workers must be within autoscaler min/max range (12,32). Requested 2
Requested number of secondary workers must be within autoscaler min/max range (10,30). Requested 0
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user3103957, Which DataProc version are you using ? Can you check these documenations [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-version-clusters#unsupported_dataproc_versions) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#autoscaling_configuration_recommendations).

Comment: sure, thanks Dhiraj!

Comment: Hi @user3103957, Could you confirm if the above links helped resolving the issue or not ?

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, They served as a good entry points for our investigation. Thanks for sharing the links!

Comment: Hi @user3103957, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#autoscaling_configuration_recommendations), you can select the same number of minimum and maximum instances for primary workers to avoid the autoscaling of the primary workers. It is recommended to scale the secondary worker. You can also check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#create_an_autoscaling_policy) for following the best practices for autoscaling.

Also, check that the dataproc version you are using is the latest and supported version. DataProc doesn’t support [these versions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-version-clusters#unsupported_dataproc_versions).